# SQL Pivot Query with aggregation & Total

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

Table-A

| ProductId | BrandName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand-1 |
| 2 | Brand-2 |
| 3 | Brand-3 |

Table-B

| DCDate | DCNo | ProductId | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-09 | 3 | 1 | 12.5 |
| 2021-03-09 | 3 | 1 | 12.6 |
| 2021-03-09 | 3 | 1 | 12.5 |
| 2021-03-09 | 3 | 2 | 10.5 |
| 2021-03-09 | 3 | 2 | 10.4 |
| 2021-03-09 | 3 | 3 | 15.5 |
| 2021-03-09 | 1 | 1 | 12.5 |
| 2021-03-09 | 1 | 3 | 15.7 |
| 2021-03-09 | 2 | 2 | 10.6 |
| 2021-03-09 | 4 | 1 | 12.7 |
| 2021-03-09 | 4 | 1 | 12.6 |

Expected Result:-

| BrandName | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brand-1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| Brand-2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Brand-3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

**Need Dynamic Pivot Query**

What i tried

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([DCNo]) from [Table-B] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + '
             from 
             (
                SELECT a.[DCNo] , b.[BrandName], count(*) as Total FROM [Table-B] a inner join [Table-A] b on a.[ProductID]=b.[ProductID] group by [DCNo] , b.[BrandName] order by DCNo, b.[BrandName]
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Total)
                for DCNo in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recreated it in a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1554/9 .
You were close but I sometimes find it easier to move all sum/count/grouping logic to the PIVOT section of the query instead. Results in simpler queries (most of the times)

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Table-A] (
  ProductId INT,
  BrandName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE [Table-B](
  DCDate DATETIME,
  DCNo INT,
  ProductId INT,
  Weight DECIMAL
)

INSERT INTO [Table-A] VALUES
(1, 'CAT'),
(2, 'APPLE'),
(3, 'PARROT')

INSERT INTO [Table-B] VALUES
('2021-03-09', 3,   1,  12.5),
('2021-03-09', 3,   1,  12.6),
('2021-03-09', 3,   1,  12.5),
('2021-03-09', 3,   2,  10.5),
('2021-03-09', 3,   2,  10.4),
('2021-03-09', 3,   3,  15.5),
('2021-03-09', 1,   1,  12.5),
('2021-03-09', 1,   3,  15.7),
('2021-03-09', 2,   2,  10.6),
('2021-03-09', 4,   1,  12.7),
('2021-03-09', 4,   1,  12.6)

-- Query
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @nullcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Determine columns
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    dcno,
    ',' + QUOTENAME([DCNo]) AS col,
    ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([DCNo]) + ', 0) AS ' + QUOTENAME([DCNo]) AS nullcol
  FROM [Table-B]
)
SELECT
  @cols += col,
  @nullcols += nullcol
FROM cte
ORDER BY dcno
SET @cols = SUBSTRING(@cols, 2, LEN(@cols)) 

-- create query
SET @query = N';with CTE AS 
(
  SELECT 
    a.BrandName, 
    a.ProductId,
    b.DCNo, 
    1 as Value
  FROM [Table-A] a
  INNER JOIN [Table-B] b
     ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId
)
SELECT BrandName ' + @nullcols + ' FROM 
(SELECT * FROM cte) p
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value)
  FOR DCNo IN (' + @cols + ')    
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.ProductId
'
-- SELECT @query
execute(@query)
```

Comment: I need this to be in order by Product Id
Also DCNO number in order

Comment: ProductId is now an aggregated value, What do you mean with 'in order by Product Id'? In what order would you like DCNO?

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1554/1  
Now the order is based on BrandName like APPLE,CAT,PARROT, I needs this to be  CAT,APPLE,PARROT order by ProductId

Comment: DCNO is showing like 1, 10,100,2,20,200, I need this to be 1,2,10,20,100,200

Comment: I changed the answer to sort dcno numerically and order by productId

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Perfect